# Does Inverter refrigerator need automatic voltage regulator?

Tags: electrical

I just recently bought LG inverter refrigerator. I am just wondering if I still need to purchase AVR - automatic voltage regulator during brown outs to protect my newly bought appliance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the LG technical specs?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Tell us more about the known defects in your power / history of brown-outs.

Comment: An inverter runs off a battery. So brownouts should not affect the inverter.

Comment: You may be overthinking this. Why would a large manufacturer produce an appliance that could not take an acceptable amount of surges and dips from the utility provider over its life cycle? Especially a refrigerator which could cause further losses in food. But if you want to install an inverter, it certainly wouldn't hurt. Just make sure its about twice the capacity of the run load since the start up of the compressor will surge pretty high. Good luck.

Comment: In this case, inverter refers to the component in the fridge that controls the compressor, not an external device that takes DC and generates AC.

Answer (score 1):

An uninterruptible power supply or UPS will protect the electronics in your fridge, however a fridge has a fairly high peak current at times so the UPS needs to be quite large (one for a computer won’t have the wattage to support the fridge).
I would recommend getting a whole house surge protector and installing it at your service panel (breaker box). With a whole house surge protector everything in the home is protected from spikes. Brown outs are not as bad with most inverters as they are smart enough in most cases to be able to operate down to 90v with no problems, if they can not function at lower voltages they just shut down for low voltage on their internal (usually) dc buss. 
So do you need a UPS, probably not, but I would suggest a whole house surge suppressor especially if you live in an area that regularly has lightning and or heavy industrial loads close to your location.